# How does Medium.com allow embeds without being vulnerable to XSS?

Tags: python, medium-editor

Medium.com allows you to paste a link into your post (a gist or YouTube video) and it will then fetch and embed that as an `<iframe>` with `<script>` tags.

How they can do that securely without opening themselves up to attackers inserting their own XSS code?

I presume they must do some sort of sanitization on the server side but how do they differentiate between trusted `<iframe>` and `<script>` tags that they have retrieved vs. others that may be inserted by an attacker?

I'd like to do something similar with Django and [Medium Editor](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor).

Answer (score 0):

They use embed.ly which

1. Does not allow  tags
2. Allows only moderated resources